# Python selenium won't wait for a list of divs to load

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to use selenium to parse the following html page:

```
<html>
    <button>Press me</button>
    <body>
        <div class="user-list ng-scope"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I press the button on the page the div is filled with a series of "loading" divs:

```
<html>
    <button>Press me</button>
    <body>
        <div class="user-list ng-scope">
            <div class="panel">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     <i class="glyphicon.glyphicon-cog.spinner.ng- 
                      scope::before"></i>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     <i class="glyphicon.glyphicon-cog.spinner.ng- 
                      scope::before"></i>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once the `<div class="panel"></div>'s` have loaded, the html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <button>Press me</button>
    <body>
        <div class="user-list ng-scope">
            <div class="panel">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice the `<i></i>` class has changed. Basically I want to use a method in Python's selenium module to wait for the `<div class="panel"></div>'s` to load. My first thought was to wait for the `<i></i>` classes to change from glyphicon.glyphicon-cog.spinner.ng-scope::before to glyphicon-chevron-right which signals that the divs have loaded. I use the following line of python code to do this:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "glyphicon-chevron-right")))
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, as the program terminates before the divs have loaded completely. Does anyone know of a way to leverage Python's selenium to wait for an arbitrary number of elements to load?

Comment: What is the `driver.wait`? How its definition looks like? Also clarify what do you mean by *"program terminates"*? You should get `TimeOutException`, right?

Comment: driver.wait is the method selenium provides for pausing a program while waiting for an element in the DOM to load. The program does not end with a TimeOutException. It simply terminates with no exceptions raised.

Comment: *"driver.wait is the method selenium provides for pausing a program..."* Can you elaborate about it a little? AFAIK WebDriver instance has no such attribute as `wait`

Comment: Here is the documentation for explicit waits in selenium: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I know what ExplicitWait is. I just want to know **how** do you use it in your code

Comment: I added the modules I imported to the example if you want to try to reproduce my error

Comment: As I thought you use ExplicitWait incorrectly as `WebDriverWait` is a class, but not an attribute of `WebDriver`. Try `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` instead of `driver.wait`

Comment: Unfortunately WebDriverWait(driver, 10) times out. I want to wait for the div's to load and that may take more than 10 seconds.

Comment: So just increase TimeOut value: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20) `

Comment: But there's no way to tell how much time it will take the divs to load. Sometimes there might be 10 divs that take a minute to load. Other times there may be only one div that takes a second.

Comment: `presence_of_all_elements_located()`  presumes that all nodes should appear at the same time and returns the list. If arbitrary number of nodes appears randomly - there is no possibility to automate it

Answer (score 1):

you should give time period to wait.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "glyphicon-chevron-right")))
```

Comment: Your code still incorrect. Note that `presence_of_all_elements_located` should receive single argument

Comment: changed the method to `visibility_of_all_elements_located`

Comment: This solution does not work. I'm getting: TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @raviraja , it's not about method to use, but about the arguments that you pass. Actually comment of Brinley confirms what I'm saying

Comment: sorry, my bad, changed the argument to Tuple, can you try this once?

Comment: your code works now but it still doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: How much time your page takes time to load? vary the 10 seconds and see whether it's working or not

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost there. As per the HTML you have shared to wait for the particular `<div>` element to be visible you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='user-list ng-scope']//i[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right']")))
```